# Access HTTP Header response inside NGRX Effect Angular

Tags: angular, http-headers, ngrx, response-headers

In my Angular application upon successfully making a POST to the server I receive a 201 response containing a location in the response headers that I wish to access inside my NGRX Effects. The location contains an id which I need in another effect to trigger a service call.

[image]

NGRX ACTION:

```
export const postJobOfferSuccess = createAction('[JobOffer] Post jobOffer success', props<{ successMessage: string, publish: boolean, final: boolean, response: HttpHeaderResponse }>());
```

NGRX EFFECT:

```
postJobOffer$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(postJobOffer),
        mergeMap(action => {
            return this.jobOfferClientService.postJobOffer(action.jobOffer).pipe(
                map((response) => postJobOfferSuccess({ successMessage: 'Success', publish: action.publish, final: action.final, response: response.HttpHeaderResponse })),
                mapErrorToAction(postJobOfferFailed)
            );
        })
    )
);
```

I would expect my postJobOfferSuccess to contain a response with the HTTPHeaderResponse, however upon inspecting my redux tab it does not show the header response. How can I access HTTPHeaderResponse inside an effect?

my redux tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service you have to listen to the response :

```js
this.http.post('http//...', payload, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
  tap(res => console.log(res)) // headers = res.headers | data = res.body
);
```